# TCP Capture + Edit

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do I make a program that proxies and transparently modifies TCP/IP traffic?

I want to make something like the program at at [endarkorbit.primochka.net](http://endarkorbit.primochka.net/)? That one is is made in java I guess, but I want to know how to do it in .net.

What the program does is that it creates a sort of a listener on the local ip ( 127.0.0.1 ) and you set the browser proxy to that and open the game. The program reads those packets/sends/manipulates etc. It certainly uses some tcp stuff, not sure what all and how.

I tried using a tcplistener, I get the data from the website into the listener but I cannot view the website or do anything.

I hope someone knows what I'm referreing to.

If it is of any use, some people used http://www.privoxy.org/ for other apps to get the same as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a little bit more complex. It's not just capture A and edit it to B.
This is a bot. I know these ones (also played DO). You have to know a lot of programming and it takes long time to do this.

Comment: This is not an answer -_-. It's an advice. And btw, I can make push bots, box bots ( no kiddin ). So why not start this ? I can send, analiyze, modify and play with the packets..

Comment: That's the easy one. But to make invisible ships visible is something different. There a some functions which are easy but when you want a good bot you have to create a lot of functions which can learn by themself. 
But when you rly want to try it.
Here is some stuff about tcp and .net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx

Comment: Well, I want a start, and of course, I wont start with antistealth, I will with something like autolock and stuff.. And giving that link which I already know butu cant make use of really doesnt get me anywhere.. Can you be a more specific please ?